# hg clone using tortoisehg throws “getaddrinfo failed” error on Windows XP

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, windows-xp-sp3

I have Windows XP installed in my system.I have installed tortoisehg-2.10-hg-2.8-x86.msi.
I have checkpoint vpn1-secuRemote installed on my system. I am trying to clone a project.But when i clone a project i get the following error

URLError: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
[command returned code 255 Tue Jul 01 22:40:02 2014]

The same worked when i connect from my office. The mercurial.ini is as follows

```
# Generated by TortoiseHg settings dialog
[ui]
username = avinash
verbose = True
```

Since it is windows xp i have placed my mercurial.ini in 
C:\Documents and Settings\avinash\mercurial.ini.

I have gone through several links in stackoverflow. But was not able to figure out . Can anyone help please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

"getaddrinfo failed" means you have problem not with TortoiseHG per se, but with resolver (DNS from client-side): no conversion hostname -> IP.

Fix it asking question on SU

Comment: What do you mean by fix it asking question on SU. I am not clear with statement.Can you please elaborate

Comment: @AvinashReddy I have already specified in one of your previous questions, that Stack Overflow is for *asking programming questions*. Super User is the same as Stack Overflow, but covers general computing; please ask there, instead of here.